# usage of [united-states] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the meaning of [united-states](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)? My interpretation would be that the question is somehow limited in scope to US. However, I've seen a few which I don't understand why they would be tagged with [united-states](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)

- [Does torture work well as an interrogation technique?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4498/does-torture-work-well-as-an-interrogation-technique) 
  Even though US is currently only country openly admitting to using torture, this doesn't make this question limited in scope to US.
- [Does circumcision lead to a net increase in quality of life?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/does-circumcision-lead-to-a-net-increase-in-quality-of-life) Obviously US is not the only country where circumcision is practiced.
- [Is it cheaper to eat fast food?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5426/is-it-really-cheaper-to-eat-fast-food) Even though US is sometimes referred to as the ["Fast Food Nation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Food_Nation), it's not the only place in the world where fast-food exists.

Answer (score 3):

I think that "united states" is probably warranted for the third question: prices of fast-food, fresh produce and TV dinners vary a lot by country. It can't be a non-geographical question, just like the food desert question.

I agree with you re: the other two questions.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with your interpretation of the tag. You make an excellent case for each of the three being inappropriate.

(The second one uses some US data to ask the question, but that doesn't make the issue US specific.)

So I went and removed the tag from each of them. Hopefully, the problem is solved, but we should keep an eye out in case others make the same mistake.

Thank you for your eagle eyes!